# How do I style a slide heading in Slidify?

Tags: css, r, markdown, slidify

It's not clear to me how to style (particularly, change the font colour of) a slide title with Slidify. I'm using the io2012 framework. For example, I have a slide like this:

```
---

## Slide title

Slide content

---
```

I set up a CSS file called `style.css` in the `assets/css/` folder and set up `h2 { color: #800000 }` but it has no effect on the colour of the slide title (it's still the default dark teal). How can I change this?

Comment: Try `slide:not(.segue) h2{color: #800000}`. CSS rules are namespaced and so you need to use the right namespace to overrule correctly. You will find the CSS in `libraries/frameworks/io2012/css/slidify.css`.